# canonical action of G acting on its subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

If one says "Suppose $H\leq G$, and let $X$ be the $G$-set $G/H$ ...",
from the word ${\it the}$, is it implied that the group action here is left multiplication/left translation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $G/H$ is the set of left-cosets of $G$ by $H$, so the implied action in this case is given by $g\cdot (g'H) = (gg')H$.